# How To Get IndexPath from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsindexpath

Imagine I have the following `NSDictionary`

```
dict = {
    "a" = [
        obj1,
        obj2,
        obj3
    ],
    "b" = [
        obj4,
        obj5
    ],
    "invalid" = [
        obj6,
        obj7,
        obj8
    ],
    "c" = [
        obj9,
        obj10,
        obj11
    ]
}
```

This data is used to populate a `TableView` using sections from the following `NSArray`:

```
arr = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];
```

I have the following method which I use to **find** an object

```
- (void)selectRowWithId:(NSNumber *)uid {
    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@)", uid];
        NSArray *filteredDictArray = [obj filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        if ([filteredDictArray count] > 0) {

            NSIndexPath *targetIndexPath = nil;
            //trying to find the NSIndexPath here

            [[self tableView] selectRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
            [self tableView:[self tableView] didSelectRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath];
        }
    }];
}
```

Say I have an object set to `obj10`.

Based on my `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` the `NSIndexPath` is `Section:2 Row:1`

How can I get this value if I only know `obj10`?

## Update (Solution)

So With a combination of the ideas behind everyone's answers and my own here is the following I used in case it's helpful for someone. BTW: This is for iOS9

```
- (void)selectRowWithId:(NSNumber *)uid {
    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@)", uid];
        NSArray *filteredDictArray = [obj filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        if ([filteredDictArray count] > 0) {

            //trying to find the NSIndexPath here
            NSIndexPath *targetIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[dict objectForKey:key] indexOfObject:filteredPersonsArray[0]] inSection:[arr indexOfObject:key]];

            [[self tableView] selectRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
            [self tableView:[self tableView] didSelectRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Is your json correct. Because for all key in dictionary it will be array.

Comment: It might be wrong, I updated the keys to contain arrays. Basically what I have is each key in the dictionary contains an array of objects. How should I display that? Feel free to edit.

Comment: Why is the section = 2? An dictionary does not sort its keys. So you have to do this. What is the code for that?Simple alphanumeric sorting? Then it should be section = 3, shouldn't it?

Comment: Section is 2 based on the NSArray of `@[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D"...]` I will add more info that might be helpful that I just found, which is how I am obtaining my object.

Comment: arks, of course. Simply counted from beginning without seeing that the third entry is behind the fourth.

Comment: Yeah I purposely added the 3rd entry, because its key not valid in the `arr` and will not show in the `TableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little bit too tricky. Sometimes usual looping is easier.

```
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL * stop) 
{
  for( NSInteger index = 0; index < [obj count]; index++ )
  {
    if ([obj[index] isEqualToString:uid])
    {
      // thats the index
      // Let's have a look-up for the section
      NSString *sectionKey = [[key substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]; //Typo
      for( NSInteger section=0; section < [arr count]; section++ )
      {
        if( [arr[section] isEqualToString:sectionKey] )
        {
          // That's the section
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Typed in Safari.

Comment: great... I'll try it now.

Comment: sorry, had a typo: usage of uid instead of key. fixed that.

Comment: Thanks. I used a combination of what i was trying out and some aspects of what you provided. I ended up using the following after my `if ([filteredPersonsArray count] > 0` statement: `NSIndexPath *targetIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[dict objectForKey:key] indexOfObject:filteredPersonsArray[0]] inSection:[arr indexOfObject:key]];`

Comment: Since this works too, I marked it as the solution, but also provided my final solution in my post. Thanks again!